# Is the swagger api tied to spring-boot?

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger

It isn't clear to me from the swagger-api docs but most of the examples I'm seeing online using both Spring-MVC and Swagger seem to be also using Spring-Boot.  Are the two inherently tied together, or is this just a correlation in the user community?

Comment: Umm, not sure what you're talking about. I believe https://github.com/adrianbk/swagger-springmvc-demo contains several non-boot samples.

Comment: OK, will look through them again then. When I  thumbed through initially, saw the "upgrading to spring boot 1.1.3"  as the last change on several of the examples. Didn't realize they weren't a uniform suite.